# Oracle improve query where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a little Problem. I want to execute that query:

```
WHERE (column1 = 'tetxt1'  and column2 = 'tetxt2' and column3 = 'tetxt3 ) 
OR (column2 = 'tetxt2' and column3 = 'tetxt3' ) 
OR (column1 = 'tetxt1' and column3 = 'tetxt3' ) 
OR (column1 = 'tetxt1' and column2 = 'tetxt2' ) 
OR ( column3 = 'tetxt3' ) 
OR ( column1 = 'tetxt1 ) 
OR ( column2 = 'tetxt2 )
```

In other words one of the where clause columns can be empty, but I need that the columns that have values will be queried with and.  So, if I have just values for column1 and column2 but not for column3, then the two will be queried with and condition. I don’t think that would work :

```
Where (column1 = 'tetxt1'  or column2 = 'tetxt2' or column3 = 'tetxt3')
```

and the first approach that I have given is not the best. Have you any Ideas how to improve the query?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: By "empty", do you mean the column value will be NULL or an empty string?

Comment: Appear to be missing a ' after 'tetxt3 on 1st line. and again on last 2 lines after tetxt1 and tetxt2 beyond that, coalese or NVL may be able to help you.

Comment: In oracle an empty String will be automatically converted in NULL I think (thats not the same in MS SQL Server). Yes, in my case it is NULL.

Comment: @user3465680 - thank you!  I did not know that, and you just solved a problem of mine!  I just started working with Oracle and I could not, for the life of me, figure out why my own query wasn't working.  That answers my question.

Comment: I am really happy that I could help you  :-) .. I am a newbie in Oracle too, and I use to compare it a lot with MS SQL Server... And that surprised me τοο....

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you get the same effect with:

```
WHERE 
column1 IN('tetxt1','tetxt2','tetxt3')
or column2 IN('tetxt1','tetxt2','tetxt3')
or column3 IN('tetxt1','tetxt2','tetxt3')
```

Comment: No, that would not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Empty" means `NULL` you can use the [COASLESCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) keyword.

```
WHERE (COALESCE(column1, 'text1') = 'tetxt1'  and COALESCE(column2, 'text2')  = 'tetxt2' and COALESCE(column3, 'text3')  = 'tetxt3 )
```

Comment: Thank you again a lot. Do you think we will have parfomance issues using a function in the where clause?

Comment: Nope. You shouldn't have any problems with it, at least not based on my experience.  You could always run your original query side-by-side with this one and time the execution of each to tell.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to hear that from one with experience like you!! I have no data to test but my original query is just lame and the or's are not the best... I will also use in my query, context indexes and contains for 2 columns... I will try coalesce there too. Thank you again!!!!!

Comment: If you have an index on any of those columns, wrapping them in a function (like COALESCE) will prevent the database from using the index.  So there could be a performance difference.

Comment: Oh, thats bad. I have checked the contains also and it is something very different. I think I will use something like that:
AND (column1 = '@@@@' OR '@@@@' IS NULL)
AND (colmn2 = '@@@@' OR '@@@@' IS NULL)
AND (CONTAINS(column, '@@@@',1)>0 OR '@@@@' IS NULL)
the '@@@@' will be the search value... The search value '@@@@' can be empty. I will try that in a stored procedure. I will add some Test data too.